# SharePoint 2013 search not working - OOTB

Tags: 2013, search

The SharePoint Search is not working on my VM machine. It was working as expected and today i receive the below errors in ULS logs. Any resolution?

> Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Ims.ImsQueryInternal : New request: Query text     'welcome', Query template '{searchboxquery}'; HiddenConstraints:  site:"`http://win-  9islubdukal:6205/sites/mikhil`"; SiteSubscriptionId: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>       QueryTemplateHelper: Query template '{searchboxquery}' transformed to query text  'welcome'.
>       ProductivitySearchFlowExecutor: New request: Query template '{searchboxquery}' transformed to query text 'welcome'.
>       Microsoft.Ceres.ContentEngine.NlpEvaluators.Tokenizer.QueryWordBreakerProducer:   Expanded query tree (language en):  StringNode(FirstChild=TokenNode(FirstChild=null,NextSibling=null,Length=1,Linguistics=True ,Token=welcome,Weight=1),NextSibling=null,Linguistics=True,Mode=And,Text=welcome,Weight=0, Wildcard=False)
>       Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.QueryPipelineFlowExecutor :  FlowExecutor done: SearchApplication=d43c0c62-7941-4e6e-9a2a-675a3af58403. ParentFlow=   SubFlowTimings: Linguistics=4  f78eb69c-5409-606b-b866-56a6aebb4ca5
>       QueryTemplateHelper: Query template '{?{searchTerms} -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople}' transformed to query text 'welcome -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople'.
>       QueryRouterEvaluator: QueryId PersonalFavorite Query, QueryRule , CorrelationId bf0c282a-da12-4427-b6fd-4dcaa60d7141, ParentCorrelationId f78eb69c-5409-606b-b866-56a6aebb4ca5, SourceId cd0b4ea8-749c-4bcb-9c27-3cd8355bb774
>       QueryRouterEvaluator: QueryId BestBet Query, QueryRule , CorrelationId 7cb2a548-2322-4db3-b7d2-9a4e1ca06cfe, ParentCorrelationId f78eb69c-5409-606b-b866-56a6aebb4ca5, SourceId 88279e87-6b55-4cd7-99a3-2cc5cc2e4924
>       Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.QueryPipelineFlowExecutor : FlowExecutor done: SearchApplication=d43c0c62-7941-4e6e-9a2a-675a3af58403. ParentFlow=Microsoft.SharePointSearchProviderFlow SubFlowTimings: Parsing=0  f78eb69c-5409-606b-b866-56a6aebb4ca5
>       Microsoft.Ceres.ContentEngine.NlpEvaluators.Tokenizer.QueryWordBreakerProducer: Expanded query tree (language en): AndNode(FirstChild=StringNode(FirstChild=TokenNode(FirstChild=null,NextSibling=null,Length=1,Linguistics=True,Token=welcome,Weight=1),NextSibling=FilterNode(FirstChild=NotNode(FirstChild=ScopeNode(FirstChild=BoundaryNode(FirstChild=TokenNode(FirstChild=null,NextSibling=null,Length=1,Linguistics=True,Token=urn:content-class:SPSPeople,Weight=1),NextSibling=null,BoundaryMode=Exact),NextSibling=null,Scope=Contentclass),NextSibling=null),NextSibling=FilterNode(FirstChild=ScopeNode(FirstChild=WildcardNode(FirstChild=null,NextSibling=null,Token=`http://win-9islubdukal:6205/sites/mikhil/`),NextSibling=null,Scope=SitePath),NextSibling=null)),Linguistics=True,Mode=And,Text=welcome,Weight=0,Wildcard=False),NextSibling=null)
>         Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.LinguisticQueryProcessingExecutor : QSC: All Annotations: ,,
>         Microsoft.Ceres.ContentEngine.NlpEvaluators.QuerySuggestionEvaluator: Query not changed.
>         Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.QueryPipelineFlowExecutor : FlowExecutor done: SearchApplication=d43c0c62-7941-4e6e-9a2a-675a3af58403. ParentFlow=Microsoft.SharePointSearchProviderFlow SubFlowTimings: Linguistics=32  f78eb69c-5409-606b-b866-56a6aebb4ca5
>        Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.QueryPipelineFlowExecutor : FlowExecutor done: SearchApplication=d43c0c62-7941-4e6e-9a2a-675a3af58403. ParentFlow=Microsoft.SharePointSearchProviderFlow SubFlowTimings: RecommendationsSecurityTrimming=0  f78eb69c-5409-606b-b866-56a6aebb4ca5
>        Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.Query.MarsLookupComponent.MarsLookupUtils: Skipping requested field Rank because this is a duplicate request
>       Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.Query.MarsLookupComponent.MarsLookupUtils: Skipping requested field DocId because this is a duplicate request
>        Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.Services.Query.AbstractQueryParameters: Query compressed from: 5631 to 1251 bytes.
>        Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.QueryPipelineFlowExecutor : FlowExecutor done: SearchApplication=d43c0c62-7941-4e6e-9a2a-675a3af58403. ParentFlow=   Microsoft.SharePointSearchProviderFlow SubFlowTimings: IndexLookupPreProcessing=2  CustomSecurityTrimmingPre=0 SecurityPreProcessing=1 PeopleExpertise=0  f78eb69c-5409-606b- b866-56a6aebb4ca5
>       Component and System=Query1-d43c0c62-7941-4e6e-9a2a-675a3af58403, Correlation I D=f78eb69c-5409-606b-b866-56a6aebb4ca5, Tenant ID=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000   Error code=0, Flow Name=Microsoft.SharePointSearchProviderFlow, Operator  Name=ParserExecutor, Message=The processing of item fails with error Cannot plan query for  index system SPbaed25517cd9. Index fragment '0' has no available cells. Cell statuses:  [Cell I.0.0 on node IndexComponent1: Cell status is set to 'not available' (cell out of  sync or seeding)]
>       Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.FlowHandleRegistry : Exceptions occurred when evaluating the flow.  Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.DataModel.EvaluationException:  Cannot plan query for index system SPbaed25517cd9. Index fragment '0' has no available  cells. Cell statuses: [Cell I.0.0 on node IndexComponent1: Cell status is set to 'not  available' (cell out of sync or seeding)]     at    Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithTryCatc h(IRecord record)     at    Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.FlowHandleRegistry.SubmitData(FlowExecutionInf o handle, InputData inputData, Stopwatch timer, String correlationId, Guid tenantId,  String query, String flowName, Int32 queryTimeoutMillis)     at   Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.FlowHandleRegistry.ExecuteFlow(String flowName, InputData input, Int32 queryTimeoutMillis)
>       ExecuteFlowInternal Flow:Microsoft.SharePointSearchProviderFlow Exception:   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.DataModel.EvaluationException: Cannot plan query for index  system SPbaed25517cd9. Index fragment '0' has no available cells. Cell statuses: [Cell  I.0.0 on node IndexComponent1: Cell status is set to 'not available' (cell out of sync or  seeding)]     at    Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithTryCatc h(IRecord record)     at   Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.FlowHandleRegistry.SubmitData(FlowExecutionInf o handle, InputData inputData, Stopwatch timer, String correlationId, Guid tenantId,  String query, String flowName, Int32 queryTimeoutMillis)     at   Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.FlowHandleRegistry.ExecuteFlow(String  flowName, InputData input, Int32 queryTimeoutMillis)
>       Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.EvaluationResult : The flow handle   37b3fd59-bf85-4a82-8083-e9e9ac0e564f for the requested flow    Microsoft.SharePointSearchProviderFlow is not in Running state. Server clean-up has been done.
>       ContentIntegrationEngine Flow Microsoft.SharePointSearchProviderFlow finished with state Aborted
>       FlowName=Microsoft.SharePointSearchProviderFlow. FlowID=37b3fd59-bf85-4a82-8083-e9e9ac0e564f. Flow ended
>        QueryRouterEvaluator: evaluation failure for query welcome -ContentClass=urn:content- class:SPSPeople against source 8413cd39-2156-4e00-b54d-11efd9abdb89
>       Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.QueryPipelineFlowExecutor :  FlowExecutor done: SearchApplication=d43c0c62-7941-4e6e-9a2a-675a3af58403. ParentFlow=Microsoft.ProductivitySearchFlow SubFlowTimings: QueryRuleConditionMatching=7   QueryTransformer=1  f78eb69c-5409-606b-b866-56a6aebb4ca5
>       Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.QueryPipelineHardWiredFlowExecutor : (FlowExecutor)eventSearchFlowDone: d43c0c62-7941-4e6e-9a2a-675a3af58403, welcome,   Microsoft.ProductivitySearchFlow, 223, WIN-9ISLUBDUKAL, Error=Cannot plan query for index system SPbaed25517cd9. Index fragment '0' has no available cells. Cell statuses: [Cell  I.0.0 on node IndexComponent1: Cell status is set to 'not available' (cell out of sync or  seeding)] f78eb69c-5409-606b-b866-56a6aebb4ca5
>       ExecuteFlowInternal FlowExecutor:Microsoft.ProductivitySearchFlow Exception:  Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.DataModel.EvaluationException: Cannot plan query for index system SPbaed25517cd9. Index fragment '0' has no available cells. Cell statuses: [Cell  I.0.0 on node IndexComponent1: Cell status is set to 'not available' (cell out of sync or   seeding)]    Server stack trace:      at    Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.EvaluationResult.ThrowExceptionsInEvaluationEn  gine()     at Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.EvaluationResult.<  GetRecords>d__8.MoveNext()     at    Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.EvaluationResult.ReadToEnd(String output)       at Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.EvaluationResult.Dispose(Boolean    isNotAfterAbortFlow)     at   Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.EvaluationResult.Dispose()     at   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.QueryPipelineComponent.ExecuteFlowInternal(S  string flowName, KeywordQueryProperties keywordProperties, Int32 timeout)     at    Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.QueryPipelineComponent.ExecuteFlow(String   flowName, KeywordQueryProperties keywordProperties, Int32 timeout)     at   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Processing.QueryRouterEvaluator.QueryRouterP roducer.ExecuteQueryFlow(String flowName, KeywordQueryProperties input)     at   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md,   Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)     at   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg,   IMessageSink replySink)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Processing.QueryRouterEvaluator.QueryRouterP roducer.ExecuteQueries(IRecord originalQueryRecord, IEnumerable`1 routingRecords,    QueryExecutionContext executionContext, IUpdateableDictionaryField`2 resultField)     at    Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Processing.QueryRouterEvaluator.QueryRouterP roducer.ProcessRecordCore(IRecord record)     at   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Executor.ProducerOperatorExecutor`1.ProcessProducerR  ecord(IRecord inputRecord)     at   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.ProductivitySearchFlowExecutor.Exe  cuteCore(KeywordQueryProperties keywordProperties)     at   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.QueryPipelineFlowExecutor.Execute( KeywordQueryProperties keywordProperties)     at   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.QueryPipelineHardWiredFlowExecutor .Execute(KeywordQueryProperties keywordProperties)     at   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.QueryPipelineComponent.ExecuteFlowInternal(I QueryPipelineFlowExecutor executor, KeywordQueryProperties keywordProperties, String  flowName, Int32 timeout)
>        Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Ims.ImsQueryInternal : Unhandled exception       Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.DataModel.EvaluationException: Cannot plan query for index system SPbaed25517cd9. Index fragment '0' has no available cells. Cell statuses: [Cell  I.0.0 on node IndexComponent1: Cell status is set to 'not available' (cell out of sync or  seeding)]    Server stack trace:      at    Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.EvaluationResult.ThrowExceptionsInEvaluationEn gine()     at Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.EvaluationResult. <GetRecords>d__8.MoveNext()     at     Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.EvaluationResult.ReadToEnd(String output)      at Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.EvaluationResult.Dispose(Boolean    isNotAfterAbortFlow)     at   Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.EvaluationResult.Dispose()     at   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.QueryPipelineComponent.ExecuteFlowInternal(S tring flowName, KeywordQueryProperties keywordProperties, Int32 timeout)     at    Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.QueryPipelineComponent.ExecuteFlow(String   flowName, KeywordQueryProperties keywordProperties, Int32 timeout)     at   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Processing.QueryRouterEvaluator.QueryRouterP roducer.ExecuteQueryFlow(String flowName, KeywordQueryProperties input)     at   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md,   Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)     at   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg,   IMessageSink replySink)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Processing.QueryRouterEvaluator.QueryRouterP roducer.ExecuteQueries(IRecord originalQueryRecord, IEnumerable`1 routingRecords,   QueryExecutionContext executionContext, IUpdateableDictionaryField`2 resultField)     at   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Processing.QueryRouterEvaluator.QueryRouterP      roducer.ProcessRecordCore(IRecord record)     at  Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Executor.ProducerOperatorExecutor`1.ProcessProducerR ecord(IRecord inputRecord)     at  Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.ProductivitySearchFlowExecutor.Exe cuteCore(KeywordQueryProperties keywordProperties)     at  Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.QueryPipelineFlowExecutor.Execute( KeywordQueryProperties keywordProperties)     at  Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.QueryPipelineHardWiredFlowExecutor .Execute(KeywordQueryProperties keywordProperties)     at  Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.QueryPipelineComponent.ExecuteFlowInternal(I QueryPipelineFlowExecutor executor, KeywordQueryProperties keywordProperties, String  flowName, Int32 timeout)     at  Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.QueryPipelineComponent.ExecuteFlow(String  flowName, KeywordQueryProperties keywordProperties, Int32 timeout)     at  Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Ims.ImsQueryInternal.Execute(QueryProperties  properties, Guid ssaId)

Comment: any other information? check the ULS logs, Event Log for more? also what is the error on search...

Comment: "Search has encountered a problem that prevents results from being returned. If the issue persists, please contact your administrator"

Comment: please check if the windows service for Search was started or not?

Comment: Deleted the search services and recreated - Ram Baan worked for me

Comment: @UserSP I had same problem, following steps in answer by n122vu solved the issue. Thanks for sharing the issue

Answer (score 10):

I had this same issue recently. [Search has encountered a problem that prevents results from being returned](http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/search-has-encountered-a-problem-that-prevents-results-from-being-returned/) held the solution that worked for me:

Basically it appears the search index partition becomes corrupted.  In this event the link becomes dead, the following steps resolved the issue:

1. Stop the Timer Service
2. Clear the configuration cache - 
        Find in %ProgramData%Microsoft\SharePoint\Config the folder where the file cache.ini exists
3. Delete every file from this folder EXCEPT cache.ini
4. Open cache.ini, delete the content and put '1' (without the quotes)
   in it and save the file
5. Restart the Timer Service
6. Index reset
7. Full crawl

Comment: Answer is perfect, following steps I solved my problem. Good Contribution to the SharePoint community.

Comment: These steps has solved this issue for me on multiple occassions.

Answer (score 5):

Next time "just" do an index reset and it should work after a full crawl.

Comment: Hi Max, is "index reset" the unique solution ? Our search farm takes about 4 days to do a full index on all our content sources, and I don't think Project Managers will agree on that. In addition, our search topology is configured to be highly available (index partitions duplicated), why does not search return results when index partitions on second server are OK ? Thanks.

Comment: Actually that should not happen in production at all. Not if you leave the systems running... index reset is just a final option if things are not working at all.

Comment: Do you mean that I should leave the system runnning until the issue is fixed ? If so, after how many time will I know that index reset should be performed ? Thanks.

Comment: Can't give you a number here. If it's longer than 4-8 hours I would reset.